# Magento 2 - Missing enable / disable cache options in Admin

Tags: magento2, cache

In Magento 2,I can't enable/disable cache In System -> Cache Management, the two options are missing from the dropdown menu. what did wrong?

It's in Default mode.

[image]

Anyone has idea on this?

Comment: Currently your mode is set to production so only Refresh Cache option will be there in drop down  and thats why you are not able to see Enable/Disable dropdown of cache.

Comment: regardless of mode it should show up. Have you tried flush cache storage or the other one option?

Comment: @Hlren can you check on my above question i have mentioned that i am on default mode not on production?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: no @ShoaibMunir

Answer (score 0):

Set developer mode, clear cache and try again

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Magento modes details:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html#mode-production

Comment: The link directs us to the same page. :)

Comment: Thank @SiarheyUchukhlebau. Answer updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You are in production or default mode. So it doesn't show enable and disable cache option.

So please change deploy mode into developer mode and now you can change cache enable or disable

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have checked this thing in Magento 2.4.3 p1, then cache enable and disable option is showing in **default** and **developer** mode and it's not showing in only **production** mode so please check your Magento Operation Mode and switch in **developer** or **default** mode then it will show...

to change the mode you can follow the followign command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set **developer**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enable/disable any cache with SSH, no need to switch to developer (and then back to production which will recompile everything):

```
php bin/magento cache:enable full_page
php bin/magento cache:disable full_page
```

To see a list of available caches:

```
php bin/magento cache:status

Current status:
                    config: 1
                    layout: 1
                block_html: 1
               collections: 1
                reflection: 1
                    db_ddl: 1
           compiled_config: 1
                       eav: 1
     customer_notification: 1
        config_integration: 1
    config_integration_api: 1
                 full_page: 0
         config_webservice: 1
                 translate: 1
                  checkout: 1
             amasty_shopby: 1
        cart2quote_license: 1
           cybersource_tax: 1
```